# Is it possible to use Customer Portal Authentication in Site.com (aka SiteForce)

Tags: site.com, portal

I have a client who would like to integrate a third party shopping cart into their Site.com website. The catch is that in order to complete the purchase, the user must first log into the  Customer Portal, and if necessary register as a portal user. I suspect that I can build a branded authentication page using the sitelogin visualforce template, but where I'm a bit unsure of is how all that will fit into Site.com.

Comment: Note that SitesForce the CMS product does not support Authenticated Sites/Portals. If you want a CMS for authenticated sites/portals you can look at Orchestra CMS. As for branding etc an authenticated sites - yes you can do that and you can even mask the URL if you want to. Not 100% true because of data access restrictions and licenses, but for the most part any Visualforce page you write can be in a Site or Authenticated portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word of caution to you...

Is it OK for the users to see the secure.force.com domain in the URL?  If you want to allow users to log in then you have to expose that to them.  There is no way around it.

- Force.com sites and Customer Portal do NOT support custom SSL certificates.  It is on the roadmap, but who knows when it will be delivered.  I'd hope that it would be delivered whenver the support for authentication on Site.com (also on roadmap) is delivered.
- The login form must be submitted over SSL (i.e., you have to set the apex:form's forceSSL="true").

Those two together mean that you have to expose the secure.force.com domain to the end user.  This is something that you can only test in production, because custom web addresses are not supported in the sandboxes.

Also, Site.com is not available in Sandboxes, so you have to do all of your development directly in production.  Or, you can do it in an unrelated Developer Edition.  Note that if you choose to do the development of the Site.com in production or an unrelated Developer Edition and the Force.com Sites + Portal in sandboxes the domains will be different.  If you have any sort of Ajax or something like that, that you'd want integrated across both, you will have to go to extra lengths (i.e., something like JSONP) that would only be necessary for development.

My 2 cents.  Wait until the custom SSL certs are available.  Wait until Site.com is made to be more development friendly.

Comment: what about a reverse proxy like ngnix? I have had good performance proxying salesforce portals behind a proxying system to get SSL AND branded host URI.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is Yes, you can. The long answer is as follows:

- A user visiting your site may view all the pages on your site, but you'd like to control the activities that they are allowed to perform. This new user with no identity or authority is automatically assigned to the guest user profile.
- You can find out exactly what a guest user can do on the Sites setting page in your org by clicking the Public Access Settings page. This determines the security profile of each and every site `visitor` before they authenticate.
- You'd need to do a little bit of coding to bring together Customer Portal and Sites.
- Set up Customer Portal with login enabled.
- Customize the login page with a custom visualforce page so that the default login page is not shown
- Also, enable self-registration for new users under Customer Portal settings so that new users can register using the default SiteRegister VF page. Again, you can script your own page, if you don't like the default page. This will create a portal user.

That's all you need to do to make Customer Portal and Site.com work together. If you want more in-depth details check out this [developer article](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites). It also lists some best practices.

Anup

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, a Site.com page functions the same as Force.com Sites? I've linked a Force.com Site to the Portal, but it's looking like Site.com is completely different.

Comment: Site.com functions completely separately from Force.com Sites, it has its own infrastructure.  Currently you'd need to link over to your Portal.

Comment: As @joshbirk mentioned, they are different entities. Check this [wiki](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Websites) out for more details.